# Calling functions from imported js library inside HTML

Tags: javascript, html, libraries

I am using [this](https://g6.antv.vision/en) library and I'm trying to use it in my HTML code.

I created a js file called g6_lib.js which looks like this:

```
import G6 from '@antv/g6';
import { GraphLayoutPredict } from '@antv/vis-predict-engine'
```

I then added this line of code into my HTML:

```
<script src = "g6_lib.js"></script>
```

However, when I try to import the library like that, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Basically, im trying to get my hands on this provided example from their site:

```
import G6 from '@antv/g6'
import { GraphLayoutPredict } from '@antv/vis-predict-engine'
const data = {
    nodes: [],
  edges: []
}
// predictLayout indicates the predicted layout type, such as 'force' or 'radial'
// 'confidence' is the confidence of the prediction
const { predictLayout, confidence } = await GraphLayoutPredict.predict(data);
const graph = new G6.Graph({
    ... // other configurations
    layout: {
    type: predictLayout
  }
})
```

I tried inserting it into `<script></script>` tags, but it still doesn't work, and I also get a console error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

for this line of code:

```
const { predictLayout, confidence } = await GraphLayoutPredict.predict(data);
```

Im fairly new with js programming and web overall, I'm sorry if im asking some trivial questions, but I would really like to learn.

there is a provided code example [here](https://g6.antv.vision/en/docs/manual/getting-started) which runs perfectly, however, it imports the library by something that's called "CDN". However, this import doesn't cover the extensibility that i'm looking for.

I'd really appreciate if someone could point out on what i'm doing wrong, and how to import such libraries properly into my HTML.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Second part of the question.
If you want to use `await` then you should make an `async` function because `await` works with `async` .
Like that.
`async function abc(){ const { predictLayout, confidence } = await GraphLayoutPredict.predict(data); // more code ..... }`
It will work fine then.